# Dome (or force field) appeared over a city (not Stephen King's Under The Dome)

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Short story of a dome (or at least a barrier) that appeared over a city overnight - it may have been New York or Manhattan. There was not any explanation or claim of responsibility. An engineer could hear a B-flat tone that it produced and that was a clue to solving it. The dome/barrier was actually a test, as the perpatrators were evaluating it as for a more large scale use/attack. I read this between 1975 and 1990 in an anthology.

Not a movie or video.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The story is *The Box* by James Blish (famous in Star Trek circles). Originally published in 1949 and republished several times, including in "The Best of James Blish" and "Beyond Control" 1972/74. It was even made into a teleplay on the show "The Secret Files of Captain Video", broadcast Sept. 5, 1953. The episode had Werner Klemperer (Col. Klink of Hogan's Heros).

> A desperate race against death as a scientist & associate, rush to save a suffocating city entombed within a mysterious encapsulating covering.

It was in the [1952 Omnibus of Science Fiction](http://www.iblist.com/book12137.htm) by Groff Conklin. I remember that story vividly, as well as a few others from that book.

[Here it is for sale](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0517453703) in the edition I remember reading (printed in 84).

Comment: The story is _The Box_ by James Blish (famous in Star Trek circles). Originally published in 1949 and republished several times, including in "The Best of James Blish" and "Beyond Control" 1972/74. It was even made into a teleplay on the show "The Secret Files of Captain Video", broadcast Sept. 5, 1953. The episode had Werner Klemperer (Col. Klink of Hogan's Heros).

I wonder if Stephen King borrowed the idea for his book.

Comment: Here is a description:
A desperate race against death as a scientist & associate, rush to save a suffocating city entombed within a mysterious encapsulating covering.

You can read it at http://www.unz.org

Answer (score 3):

I feel like a story like this was discussed in the Incomparable podcast but I can't find the reference anymore... I did some searching and all I could find was All Flesh Is Grass (1965) by Simak... OK the book I was thinking about was Spin from Wilson, so definitely not what you're looking for... Hope this helps...

Comment: Not All Flesh is Grass, but thanks for the input.

Answer (score -2):

"The Dome" by Steven Milhauser

Comment: Hello and welcome to SFFSE!  Could you give some description of the story you have provided to help the OP make a determination of whether this is the story they are searching for?